# JSP+Spring Security авторизация

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, jstl

[image: login.jsp]

У меня такая проблема: сделал(по туториалам) регистрацию с помощью Spring Security, MVC, JPA and Hibernate но не понимаю как это работает на стороне вюшки. Вю используюет JSP, jstl, Spring tags. Я не понимаю как передаются данные с форм и как получить на стороне вю авторизированого пользователя и его данные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «[edit]», расположенную под метками вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Все и так предельно ясно:

> Spring Security is a framework that focuses on providing both
>   authentication and authorization to Java applications. Like all Spring
>   projects, the real power of Spring Security is found in how easily it
>   can be extended to meet custom requirements
>
> Features
>
> Comprehensive and extensible support for both Authentication and
>   Authorization Protection against attacks like session fixation,
>   clickjacking, cross site request forgery, etc Servlet API integration
>   Optional integration with Spring Web MVC Much more...
>   Принг безопасности является основой, которая фокусируется на предоставлении как аутентификации и авторизации для Java-приложений. Как и все проекты Spring, реальная власть Spring Security находится в том, как легко она может быть расширена для удовлетворения требований пользовательских

Принг безопасности является основой, которая фокусируется на предоставлении как аутентификации и авторизации для Java-приложений. Как и все проекты Spring, реальная власть Spring Security находится в том, как легко она может быть расширена для удовлетворения требований пользовательских

Особенности

Всестороннее и расширяемая поддержка для аутентификации и авторизации защиты от атак типа фиксации сессии, ClickJacking, перекрестное запроса сайта подлог и т.д. интеграции API сервлетов Факультативным интеграции с Spring Web MVC И многое другое ...

Comment: Повышай навыки гугления

Comment: Добро пожаловать на [ru.so]. Ввиду тематики сайта ответ должен содержать перевод на русский язык. Добавьте пожалуйста перевод.